# Can I change bot framework timeout value?

Tags: botframework

It seems the Web Chat UI has a timeout of 15 seconds, at which point "couldn't send, retry" is shown.

Can I change the value of that timeout? I want to set it to 60 seconds.

Comment: what happens on other channels? try the emulator and see if it gives you an error is my suggestion.